# CyberArk ITATS004E Authentication failure for User in python script

Tags: python, bash, ssh, cyber-ark

I'm trying to implement a python script that executes local bash scripts or simple commands on remote CyberArk machines. Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for ip in IP_LIST:
        bash_cmd = f"ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no {USER}%{LOCAL_USER}%{ip}@{PROXY} 'bash -s' < {BASH_SCRIPT}"
        exit_code = subprocess.call(bash_cmd, shell=True)
        print(exit_code)
        bash_cmd = f"scp {USER}%{LOCAL_USER}%{ip}@{PROXY}:server_info_PY.txt ."
        exit_code = subprocess.call(bash_cmd, shell=True)
        print(exit_code)
```

The main problem is that i get this CyberArk authentication error most of the times, but not always, so it's kind of random and i don't know why:

```
PSPSD072E Perform session error occurred. Reason: PSPSD033E Error receiving PSM For SSH server 
response (Extra information: [289E [4426b00e-cc44-11ec-bca1-005056b74f99] Failed to impersonate as 
user <user>. Error: [ITATS004E Authentication failure for User <user>.
```

In this case the ssh exit code is 255, but if i check sshd service logs on the remote machine, there are no errors. I even tried with the os library to execute bash commands, but I got same result.
I was thinking of multiple ssh sessions hanging after executing this script a lot of times, but on the remote machine i only find the one i'm using.
Could someone explain what is happening or do you have any ideas?

**Notes:** I don't have any access to the PSM server, that is stored in the variable *PROXY*

**Edit 1:** I tried to use Paramiko library to create the ssh connection, but i get an authentication error related to Paramiko and not related to CyberArk. I also tried Fabric library which is based on Paramiko, so it didn't work.
If i try to run the same ssh command manually from my terminal it works and i can see that it first connects to the *PROXY* and then to the *ip* of the remote machine. From the script side it looks like he can't even connect to the *PROXY* because of the CyberArk authentication error.

**Edit 2:** I logged some informations about all commands running when executing the python script and i found out that the first command which is launched is */bin/sh/ -c* plus the ssh string:

```
/bin/sh -c ssh <user>@<domain>
```

Could be this the main problem? The prepending of /bin/sh -c? Or it's a normal behaviour when using subprocess library? There is a way to just execute the ssh command without this prepend?

**Edit 3:** I removed *shell=True* but got same auhtentication error. So, if i execute manually the ssh command i get no error, but if it is executed from the python script i get the error, but i can't find any contradiction at proccess level using *ps aux* in both cases.

Comment: You're setting `shell=True` in your calls to `subprocess.call`. That means "execute this command using the shell", which means "run it using `/bin/sh -c`".

Comment: As soon as i can i'll try your solution. Something happened on CyberArk this weekend and i don't have any access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the authentication error is kind of random, I just added a while loop that resets known_hosts file and runs the ssh command for *n* retries.

```
succeeded_cmd_exec = False
retries = 5
while not succeeded_cmd_exec:
    if retries == 0:
        break
    bash_cmd = f'ssh-keygen -f "{Configs.KNOWN_HOSTS}" -R "{Configs.PROXY}"'
    _, _, exit_code = exec_cmd(bash_cmd)
    if exit_code == 0:
        radius_password = generate_password(Configs.URI, Configs.PASSWORD)
        bash_cmd = f"sshpass -p \"{radius_password}\" ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no {Configs.USER}%{Configs.LOCAL_USER}%{ip}@{Configs.PROXY} 'ls'"
        stdout, stderr, exit_code = exec_cmd(bash_cmd)
        if exit_code == 0:
            print('Output from SSH command:\n')
            print(stdout)
            succeeded_cmd_exec = True
        else:
            retries = retries - 1
            print(stdout)
            print('SSH command failed, retrying ... ')
            print('Sleeping 15 seconds')
            time.sleep(15)
    else:
        print('Reset known hosts files failed, retrying ...')
if retries == 0 and not succeeded_cmd_exec:
    print(f'Failed processing IP {ip}')
```

The *exec_cmd* function is defined like this:

```
def exec_cmd(bash_cmd: str):
    process = subprocess.Popen(bash_cmd, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    process.wait()
    return stdout.decode('utf-8'), stderr.decode('utf-8'), process.returncode
```